# Installed Ubuntu into an old notebook, unreadable screen artifacts

Tags: screen

I installed Ubuntu on this old netbook, during the installation the screen worked properly, when I booted in after installation, this happened.

Is there a way to fix it? As you can see, the cursor can go into the bit(?) side of the screen, I didn't find any explanation on the web (or I did the wrong research since I'm not native).

[image]

this is the output of `sudo lshw-C video`:

```
*-display:0             
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Mobile 945GSE Express Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 03
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:f7e00000-f7e7ffff ioport:dc00(size=8) memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:f7dc0000-f7dfffff memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display:1 UNCLAIMED
       description: Display controller
       product: Mobile 945GM/GMS/GME, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2.1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
       version: 03
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7e80000-f7efffff
```

I rebooted to see what could've happen without the vga in, same problem until the vga goes in, but this time, some unreadble screen artifacts are in the top left of the screen:

[image]

Edit 2: My lurking into the web, following the comment suggestion, made me download the drivers directly from intel. This file "Intel(R) Graphics Driver - Linux* [Intel-3.4.3006-20051209.i386.tar.gz] " is related to Xorg, after extracting the tar.gz, there's no ".sh" to run and the readme file doesn't really explain what to do. "

https://downloadmirror.intel.com/9722/eng/readme.txt " this is the readme file in question.

please help, I can't install the driver, I have zero idea on where I need to start to compile this driver, I never needed (maybe i was lucky) to configure a xorg file before. please help

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using and what is the output of *sudo lshw -C video*

Comment: ubuntu-16.04.4-desktop-i386, ok before write the output i'm going to write, just out of curiosity I connected the screen via vga to a screen, the screen became crystal clear and I had in first place the possibility to get the terminal out. (i'm editing from the netbook, wait a few)

Answer (score 2):

This issue is likely an issue with your graphics driver. It may not be able to render the graphical user interface that Ubuntu sets up for you.

See if you can open up the terminal and reinstall your graphics driver from command line. There are many ways to do this, so instead of providing you a command that may or may not work, I will link you to a page that goes over installing a graphics driver on ubuntu. You can also just google that exact phrase.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VideoDriverHowto

Comment: I tried to do what you did suggest, i downloaded the proper driver and with a trickery with Alien i run the package as .deb.  it didn't work, is there a possibility it is a deafult screen ratio property that mess things up?